# Host Static Website with IIS Express

Tags: ajax, webserver, iis-express

Is it possible to host just static files on IISExpress without a web.config?

I have a html5 Application Prototype (no serverside code) and I would like to host the website on IISExpress Webserver because there are a few json files simulating a REST-API which I access with AJAX.

There is a main.html file and some api/data.json files.

When Im creating a VS-Project everything works fine.

I delete all config and VS-related files and added the site manually with

```
appcmd add site /name:"HTMLStandalone" /bindings:http/*:56668 /physicalPath:"C:\Users\me\somefoler\myapp"
```

UPDATE: works fine, it results in the following entry in the applicationhost.config

```
<site name="HTMLStandalone" id="4">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\me\somefolder\myapp" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56668" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

when I start the site

```
 iisexpress.exe /site:HTMLStandalone
```

the process fails:

```
Failed to translate binding to url prefix *:56668
Registration completed for site "HTMLStandalone"
Failed to process sites
Report ListenerChannel stopped due to failure; ProtocolId:http, ListenerChannelI
d:0
HostableWebCore activation failed.
```

Is it possible to host just static files without a web.config?

Answer (score 0):

web.config file is not mandatory. It seems your appcmd.exe command is little off... Run following command instead

appcmd add site /name:"HTMLStandalone" /bindings:**http/*:56668:**  /physicalPath:"C:\Users\me\somefoler\myapp"

Note that, to run this site you must be running as administrator. If you want to run as non-administrator, run the following command

appcmd add site /name:"HTMLStandalone" /bindings:**http/*:56668:localhost**  /physicalPath:"C:\Users\me\somefoler\myapp"

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the appcmd syntax was ok, as it produced a correct entry in the applicationhost.config (see updated)

Comment: when I add the :localhost flag as in your second example it works! But Im running the iisexpress.exe in a cmd-window as Administrator. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the iis.net website

> You can also use the /path option to run a site directly from a
>   folder. This option works for any type of application, including
>   static HTML, ASP.NET, PHP, and WCF. By default, IIS Express will run
>   the site on `http://localhost:8080/`. For a managed website, such as
>   ASP.NET, IIS Express will use .NET 4.0. You can use the /port and /clr
>   options to override these default values.

In my case this was not enough. /path and /config flags are not combinable. I wanted a custom applicationhost.config file (in order to add the mime-extenstions for json and text/cache-manifest)

The current solution was to add the bindings:http/*:56668:**localhost**

Alternativly to make the site available on the (local) network, you can use the dns-name of your pc/server, e.g. bindings:http:/*:56668:**my-pc**